# Upload Multipart files Completion block

Tags: alamofire, beta

I'm using alamofire5 beta and I can't find the encodingResult that was used in previous versions.

This is my code function:

```
static func postComplexPictures(complexId: String, pictures: [UIImage], completion:@escaping (DataResponse<Data?>) -> Void) {
    let url = K.ProductionServer.baseURL + "/api/v1/complex/" + complexId + "/pictures"
    let token: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Token") ?? ""
    let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + token
    let bundleId: String = Bundle.footballNow.bundleIdentifier!

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [HTTPHeaderField.authentication.rawValue: bearerToken,
                                HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue: ContentType.multipart.rawValue,
                                HTTPHeaderField.bundleIdentifier.rawValue: bundleId]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for image in pictures {
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "pictures[\(index)]", fileName: "picture", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }
        }
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers).response(completionHandler: completion)
}
```

The .response actually calls my block, but it returns too quick for the images to be uploaded and I don't have a reference to the uploading status of the images.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to say that there is no encoding result in Alamofire 5! Instead, failures in multipart encoding, and the async work required to encode it, are now part of the same request path as everything else. So you'll get any errors in your `response` calls, just like any other request. So if your request is finishing quickly, check the error, as the multipart encoding may have failed.